# How do you create a project from scratch using Brunch.io, without using their skeletons?

Tags: terminal, project, package, bower, brunch

I couldn't find any Brunch.io skeleton that suited my project and so I tried to start from scratch and create my own. But it wasn't before long that I was only scratching my head instead.

Could someone please explain how to start a new project in an empty folder and integrate it with Brunch, using just the terminal and a text editor?

PLEASE DO NOT USE EXISTING SKELETONS

Ideally I'm looking for a tutorial like this: https://coderwall.com/p/pijtcq, but with more detail at each step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to take a look at dead-simple brunch, this is official skeleton which is *maximally minimal*.

https://github.com/brunch/dead-simple

Maybe still take it and add your own framework, lang plugins and stuff.

Or, you can re-create your own, by following the same path: add `bower.json`, `brunch-config` and `package.json`. That's it, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I had already looked at the that skeleton before posting my question, I'll take another look at it today. I recall having some trouble with it before, my js (a simple console.log and alert) wouldn't fire. Is this because of any setting perhaps?

Comment: Yup, tried again and the custom js I've written gets concatenated but doesn't fire. I don't get it...

Comment: I selected your answer as the correct one since it did make me understand how Brunch works which answered my original question. But there are still many undocumented areas or at least the important information is deeply hidden in the documentation. Hope these get better in time because Brunch is absolutely a fantastic tool to work with otherwise.

Comment: Regarding your scripts not firing/getting triggered, not sure if you know this already - I think by default, brunch now assumes you're declaring modules (a-la RequireJS style) so you essentially need to tell where in your HTML it should *require("app")* (or whatever name it packs your module as). There is an option to disable this and keep it flat however. I can't recall off the top my head but its something in brunch-config like "options: modules: false".

Answer (score 3):

Going through the dead-simple skeleton helped me understand how Brunch works but I couldn't fire any of my custom js. But I finally, got it... add this code to the brunch-config file to execute all your js files as expected.

```
modules:
  definition: false
  wrapper: false
```

Not sure why this isn't the default behaviour or why it isn't explicitly mentioned anywhere. I spent ages sifting through the net to get this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this part of the documentation:

- https://github.com/brunch/brunch-guide/blob/master/content/en/chapter04-starting-from-scratch.md